# Add label text in detailTextLabel as well as text pulled from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, detailtextlabel

I'm trying to enter static text in a detailTextLabel which gives the information that is being pulled in some context.

At the moment I have `[[cell detailTextLabel] setText: [[artist valueForKey:@"listeners"] description]];`
 Which works great for pulling the number of listeners, however I want the cell to show something like "Listeners : (number of listeners)".

What I can't get to work here is having the "Listeners : " before the number which is pulled from the JSON.

Comment: cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Listeners: %d", [[artist valueForKey:@"listeners"] count]]; ??

Comment: You should spend some time with the NSString class reference.

Comment: @HMHero, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *listeners = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Listeners: %i", [[artist valueForKey:@"listeners"] description]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = listeners;
```